# GtkImage isn't updating and opencv won't free images

Tags: c++, c, opencv, gtk

I'm trying to display video from a webcam. I capture the images from the webcam using opencv and then I try to display them on a GtkImage.

This is my code, which runs in a seperate thread.

```
  gpointer View::updateView(gpointer v)
{
    IplImage *image;
    CvCapture *camera;
    GMutex *mutex;
    View *view;

    view=(View*)v;
    camera=view->camera;
    mutex=view->cameraMutex;

    while(1)
    {
        g_mutex_lock(view->cameraMutex);
        image=cvQueryFrame(camera);
        g_mutex_unlock(view->cameraMutex);

        if(image==NULL) continue;

        cvCvtColor(image,image,CV_BGR2RGB);

        GDK_THREADS_ENTER();
        g_object_unref(view->pixbuf);
        view->pixbuf=gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data((guchar*)image->imageData,GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE,image->depth,image->width,image->height,image->widthStep,NULL,NULL);

        gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf(GTK_IMAGE(view->image),view->pixbuf);
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(view->image);
        GDK_THREADS_LEAVE();
        usleep(10000);
    }

}
```

What happens is that one image is taken from the webcam and displayed and then the GtkImage stops updating.

In addition, when I try to use cvReleaseImage, I get a seg fault which says that free has been passed an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTK is an event-driven toolkit, like many others. What you're doing is queuing the new images to draw in an infinite loop, but never give GTK a chance to draw them. This is not how a [message pump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_pump) works. You need to give a hand back to GTK, so it can draw the updated image. The way to do that is explained in [gtk_events_pending](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-General.html#gtk-events-pending) documentation.

Moreover, allocating/drawing/deallocating a gdk-pixpuf for each image is sub-optimal. Just allocate the buffer once out of your loop, draw on it in your loop (it will overwrite the previous content), and display it. You only need to reallocate a new buffer if your image size changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to work with GtkImgae, but my guess is that you are not passing the newer images to the window. You need something like the native cvShowImage to execute inside the loop. If it isn't that I don't know.

Also You shouldn't release the image used for capture. OpenCV allocates and deallocates it itself.

EDIT: Try using the OpenCV functions for viewing image and see if the problem is still there.